# TKinter. Показ массива вводимых данных в режиме реального времени

Tags: python, tkinter

Вводятся подряд числа в одно и тоже окно путем нажатия кнопки "добавить". Написали и добавили в массив, опять написали и вновь добавили и так далее

Стоит задача: пользователь должен видеть визуально введенный массив (список переменных)

Как в том же самом окне, куда вводятся данные, реализивать показ вводимых данных в режиме реального времени?

Что уже есть, по блокам (внизу блок с вопросом):

```
from tkinter import*

    # Массив вводимых данных

array_of_rand_var = [] 

#Геометрия окна

master = Tk()

master.title("Вводим и видим")

master.geometry('500x250')

    # Блок с параметрами  массива переменных
    # Объявляется поле ввода и его позиция
    # Описывается текст к полю ввода и позиция текста

Buffer_rand_var = StringVar()

Buffer_rand_var_entry = Entry(master, textvariable = Buffer_rand_var)

Buffer_rand_var_entry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

Buffer_rand_var_label = Label(master, text='Какую переменную вносим в массив?')

Buffer_rand_var_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

    # Отображаем вводные данные в отдельном поле, но В ТОМ ЖЕ ОКНЕ

        ВОТ ТУТ ПРЕДПОЛАГАЛОСЬ СОЗДАТЬ БЛОК ВЫВОДА ВВОДИМЫХ ДАННЫХ

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Не совсем понял, в какой момент значения должны добавляться в массив. Если вы хотите, чтобы пользователь видел свои числа, то он вроде как видит их при вводе :)*

Могу предложить такую идею: пользователь вводит одно число, затем при нажатии *пробела* строка очищается, число добавляется в массив и содержимое массива выводится в окно.

**Это можно сделать так:**

**1.** Добавим еще один `Label` для отображения массива:

```
array_show = Label(master, text='Массив:')
array_show.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")
```

**2.** Установим *"слушатель пробелов"* на поле ввода:

```
Buffer_rand_var_entry.bind("<space>", array_add)
```

**3.** Добавим функцию, которая будет добавлять элементы в массив:

```
def array_add(event):
    global array_of_rand_var

    var = int(Buffer_rand_var_entry.get())
    array_of_rand_var.append(var)
    Buffer_rand_var_entry.delete(0, END)
    array_show['text'] = f'Массив: {array_of_rand_var}'
```

---

### Полный код:

```
from tkinter import*

array_of_rand_var = [] 

def array_add(event):
    global array_of_rand_var

    var = int(Buffer_rand_var_entry.get())
    array_of_rand_var.append(var)
    Buffer_rand_var_entry.delete(0, END)
    array_show['text'] = f'Массив: {array_of_rand_var}'

#Геометрия окна

master = Tk()

master.title("Вводим и видим")

master.geometry('500x250')

Buffer_rand_var = StringVar()

Buffer_rand_var_entry = Entry(master, textvariable = Buffer_rand_var)
Buffer_rand_var_entry.bind("<space>", array_add)

Buffer_rand_var_entry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

Buffer_rand_var_label = Label(master, text='Какую переменную вносим в массив?')

Buffer_rand_var_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

array_show = Label(master, text='Массив:')
array_show.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Я изменил вопрос. То, что Вы предложили, тоже подойдет. Спасибо!